# how to prevent the element from disappear while the cursor is on it

Tags: javascript, css, timeout

I have some dropdown:

```
<div id="projectPopup">
 <h1 id="projectTitle">Select Project</h1>
 <div class="projectOption" style="background: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.6);">Test project for time tracking</div>
 <div class="projectOption">TimeTracking</div>
</div>
```

It appears after I click on link, and It get display: flex style;
Also this click start Timeout:

```
 clockifyButton.popupTimer = setTimeout(() => {
          popup.style.display = "none";
          startWithDescription();
        }, 5000);
```

And after 5s elem get display: none style, I need to have it with display: flex, while cursor is on it, how I can do this? Thanks in Forward!!!

```
#projectPopup {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 85%;
  top: 0;
  width: 230px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 999;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); /* Цвет фона */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Параметры тени */
}
```

This is styles of popup

Answer (score 0):

You could try to start the popupTimer on the mouseleave event. But it would be important to control the timer in the mouseenter event, removing the old counter, otherwise you will have lot of counters running at the same time.